# Strange full text search performance issue on simple ordered query on a large table

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, full-text-search, sql-order-by, large-data-volumes

My table has about 7M records and its structure is like follows:

```
create table Locations (LocationID (PK, int, not null),LocationName varchar(100) NOT NULL  /*e.g. 'Paris'*/, ItemsNo (int, null), ICode char(1) null /*e.g. 'C'*/, LocationExtended nvarchar(max) null)
```

HTML version here:
*"create table Locations (LocationID (PK, int, not null),LocationName varchar(100) NOT NULL, ItemsNo (int, null), ICode char(1) null, LocationExtended nvarchar(max) null)"*

My query is really simple:

```
select top 20 LocationName, ItemsNo from Locations where contains(LocationExtended,@SearchTerms) and Icode='C' and ItemsNo is not null order by ItemsNO desc
```

HTML version here: *"select top 20 LocationName, ItemsNo from Locations where contains(LocationExtended,@SearchTerms) and Icode='C' and ItemsNo is not null order by ItemsNO desc"*

Of course there is a full-text catalog for the LocationExtended field.

Now let's play a little with the parameter @SearchTerms and with the indexes:

If I only have a clustered Index on the LocationID column I get FAST execution times for @SearchTerms='Paris and France' (because there are a very few records in the LocationExtended field containing both Paris and France keywords) and SLOW execution times for @SearchTerms='France' (because there are thousands of records in LocationExtended field, for every city/town in France).

In other words the results are something like:
for @SearchTerms='Paris and France' returns: "Paris" and "Paris North" and "South Paris"
for @SearchTerms='France' returns "Paris", "Nice", "Marseille",...., etc...

Because I need both scenarios to run fast I created a non clustered index on the Locations table with Icode and ItemsNO columns and LocationID included column.

By making this new index I got the results reversed: super fast execution times for @SearchTerms='France' but slow times for @SearchTerms='Paris and France'

Now I am stuck at this point.

I mention that I am running SQL Server 2008 on Windows 2003 Server

Any ideea would be appreciated.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Finally this worked out for me:

Indexes: clustered Index on the LocationID and nonclustered index on ItemsNO with LocationID as included colums

The query:
`select
TOP 20 * from ( select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ItemsNO DESC) as RowID,ItemsNO,LocationName 
FROM
Locations 
where
contains(LocationExtended,@SearchTerms) and ItemsNO>0 and ICode='C') t`

This reduced execution time from 850 ms to ~ 45 ms